# php how to detect the extension of a file

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using curl to download different files (e.g .doc, .jpg, jpeg , docx etc) from a webmail so I would like to know how find this extension because the link that I'm using(e.g example.com/file=3838438) basically outputs the file content but there is no file extension specified in the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the MIME types, not the extension (which is unreliable).  The MIME type is a portable way to identify the file type.  Examples are `image/jpeg` and `text/html`.

First, check whether that site tells you the mime type in the HTTP response.  You want to look for the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header.

If that isn't useful, you can use [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) or [`finfo_buffer`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php) to guess mime types.  These are available from PECL, or in PHP 5.3 and later.

In older versions of PHP, you can use [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

Comment: is there any function to extract the content-type header ? or should I just get the whole header and extract the content-type with regex ?

Comment: @Michael, with curl you can use a `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` callback, and check that the line starts with "Content-Type."

Comment: @Michael: You could also simply use `$headers = get_headers($url,1);` and read the type in `$headers["Content-Type"]`

Comment: @mario, but he's downloading them with curl anyway.  `get_headers` would do an unnecessary extra GET request.

Comment: I knew about headerfunction from curl but I would have to change the curl options in the curl function so I think @mario solutions is simpler, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a Un*x hosted environment, you can call exec('file ' . $file_path, $result) to have the system do an analysis of the file.  Check $result for it's answer.

It will have something like:

Filename: ASCII text
Filename: PDF document, version 1.3

etc.

Comment: yes, it's unix environment but I was looking to get the extension before to save it and even if I save it first and then "rename" it seems that I need another workaround to set the extension e.g from PDF document, version 1.3 I need to "guess" this is a .pdf document .

Comment: You would really want to prevent injection on `@file_path` if you go with that solution. Atleast when working with user specified data.

Comment: Using finfo_file or finfo_buffer as Mathew suggested does the same thing without an exec.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *have* to use curl, here is how you could do it using straight PHP.

Note: It is possible to set headers, credentials etc. while using fopen() to fetch URL's using the [HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

```
<?php

class DownloadWithExtension
{
    // array for caching mimetypes
    public $mimetypes = array();

    // create mimetype cache when instantiated
    public function __construct() {
        // iterate through /etc/mime.types and create a hash with
        // mime-types as keys and the first extension as the value.
        foreach(preg_grep('/(^#)|(^\s+$)/',
                file('/etc/mime.types'), PREG_GREP_INVERT) as $line) {
            $minfo = preg_split('/\t+/', $line);
            if (count($minfo) > 1) {
                $this->mimetypes[$minfo[0]] = trim(array_shift(explode(' ', $minfo[1])));
            }
        }
    }

    // download $url and save as $prefix while automatically
    // determining appropriate extension.
    // @param $url - URL to download
    // @param $prefix - Filename to save to (without extension)
    // @return filename used
    public function get($url, $prefix) {
        $mimetype = NULL;
        $filename = NULL;
        $src = fopen($url, 'r');
        if (! $src) {
            throw new Exception('Failed to open: ' . $url);
        }
        $meta = stream_get_meta_data($src);
        foreach($meta['wrapper_data'] as $header){
            if (preg_match('/^content-type: ([^\s]+)/i', $header, &$matches)) {
                $mimetype = $matches[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        $extension = @$this->mimetypes[$mimetype];
        // default to .bin if the mime-type could not be determined
        $filename = sprintf('%s.%s', $prefix, $extension ? $extension : 'bin');
        $dst = fopen($filename, 'w');
        if (! ($dst && stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dst) &&
                fclose($src) && fclose($dst))) {
            throw new Exception('An error occurred while saving the file!');
        }
        return $filename;
    }
}

$d = new DownloadWithExtension();
$url = 'http://example.com?file=3838438';
$filename = $d->get($url, '/tmp/myfile');
print(sprintf("Saved %s as %s\n", $url, $filename));
```